# What is the easiest way to generate an efficient implementation of a Java interface at runtime?

Tags: java, interface, code-generation

Starting with one Java base-interface, I want others to be able to extend this interface, directly or indirectly, and add bean properties and behavior to it, as a plugin system.

Then, **at runtime**, on the user computer, I would find all those interfaces and generate a single big class that implements them all. The fields required for the bean properties would be generated automatically, while the behavior defined in the interfaces would be implemented as static methods of an helper class (created by the plugin developers) that take the appropriate interface as first parameter, so the implementation of the interface method would delegate to a static method, passing "this" as first parameter.

This is similar to how Scala implements it's traits.

I see 3 ways of doing this:

1. Use Java's dynamic proxies, which are based on reflection.
2. Generate the source-code as a string, and compile it at runtime.
3. Use some bytecode manipulation library to generate the class at runtime.

Option 1 is the easiest, but least efficient, and therefore I want a better solution. Option 2 would give me an efficient implementation, but is rather ugly.

While I have seen several libraries that can do option 3, they all seem to require that I learn Java's assembler language first, which I take as a very time-consuming activity, with little benefits in the end..

Since I don't want to learn any assembler, JVM or otherwise, is option 2 my best bet, or are there libraries that can generate dynamic proxies without me using JVM assembler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Javassist](http://www.jboss.org/javassist). With it, you can make runtime changes to classes using a straight-forward API. You don't need to know about java "black magic" to use it.

Comment: I found this example here http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/24/add-logging-at-class-load-time-with-instrumentation.html, that was easier for me to understand, than the BCEL example.

Comment: Here from Javaassist home page: "Javassist provides source-level abstraction; programmers can modify a class file without detailed knowledge of the Java bytecode. They do not have to even write an inserted bytecode sequence"

Answer (score 1):

When using [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/) you don't have to know java assembler. Lok at [this proxy](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4804).

Comment: In this example, you still need to add things like "il.append(new ALOAD(0))", which is JVM assembler. I found Javaassist example easier to follow.